# How to get beautiful soup get_text() to consider line spacing for paragraph tags

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to convert html to text. Using BeautifulSoup library.
However, it doesn't consider spacing (or new line) for paragraph tags

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
test_input = '<html><p>this is sentence 1</p><p>this is sentence 2</p></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(test_input, 'html.parser')
print(soup.get_text())
```

Output: `this is sentence 1this is sentence 2`

Expectation: `this is sentence 1 this is sentence 2`

Need help with understanding if BeautifulSoup can somehow handle that or there is any alternative library that could be used?

Comment: you need space between those 2 sentences??

Comment: yes. Since these are surrounded by paragraph tags in the original html, I would want these to be in different lines so that I know these are different paragraphs

Comment: @NishantSaraswat : Please mark answer as correct if you found what you are looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as mentioned below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
test_input = '<html><p>this is sentence 1</p><p>this is sentence 2</p></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(test_input, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all('p')
output = " ".join([p1.text for p1 in data])
```

output will be

```
this is sentence 1 this is sentence 2
```

if you want it in new line just change this line

```
output = "\n".join([p1.text for p1 in data])
```

and output will be

```
this is sentence 1 
this is sentence 2
```